# Why are we increasing Simcha when it isn't Adar yet?

Tags: rosh-chodesh-new-month, simchah-joy-happiness

Rosh Chodesh is 2 days as today is the 30th of Shevat. Adar doesn't actually begin until tonight. Yet the sense of mishenichnas Adar marbim b'simcha seems to hold sway even today, and not just in the additional simcha of Rosh Chodesh.

The most local proof to this is the local policy on Purim Torah, which only mentions "Rosh Chodesh" and not "The beginning of Adar" but other sites seem to bring in the idea of Adar before the month. On an old [thread](http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/mishenichnas-adar-marbim-bsimcha) on the Yeshiva World, I found this statement: "Even though it's really 30 shvat, it's still called rosh chodesh adar." But the [Chabad](http://www.chabad.org/calendar/view/day.asp?tdate=2/27/2017) website has its mention of Mishenichnas only on the entry for the second day. So I don't think this is a meta-question.

Is it halachically the case that on a 2 day Rosh Chodesh, the upcoming month is considered as if it has begun even on the first day?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it halachically the case that on a 2 day Rosh Chodesh, the upcoming
>   month is considered as if it has begun even on the first day?

The basic answer is yes, unless specific language is given to differentiate. Thus if one says *the start of Adar* or *Rosh Chodesh Adar*, the the first day of Rosh Chodesh is meant. If one explicitly says *the first of Adar* then the second day of Rosh Chodesh is meant.

As an example, the Rambam says that if someone makes a neder for "this month", the thirtieth day of the month (first day of Rosh Chodesh) is treated as the next month and the neder has expired. Thus we see that when someone speaks of "Rosh Chodesh" for halachic purposes, then we use the first day of Rosh Chodesh as *beginning the month* based on the principle that the Torah speaks *Belashon Adam* under normal circumstances

[Rambam Nedarim - Chapter 10](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/973889/jewish/Nedarim-Chapter-10.htm)

**Halacha 3**

> שאני שותה חדש זה אסור בשאר ימי החדש אבל ביום ראש חודש יהיה מותר אף על
>   פי שהיה חדש חסר שאני טועם חדש אחד אסור שלשים יום גמורים מעת לעת נדר
>   חדש סתם אסור שלשים יום מעת לעת מספק:
>
> [When one takes a vow, saying:] "I will not drink [wine] during this
>   month," he is forbidden in the remaining days of the month. He is,
>   however, permitted on the day of the following Rosh Chodesh even if
>   the month is lacking.8 [If he took a vow, saying]: "I will not drink
>   [wine] for an entire month," he is forbidden for 30 full days. [If he
>   said]: I will not drink [wine] for a month," he is forbidden for 30
>   full days because of the unresolved question.9

As explained

> *Footnote 8*
>
> A month which is lacking is a month of 29 days [as opposed to a month
>   of 30 days; see Hilchot Kiddush HaChodesh, chs. 1-3, which discusses
>   the principles determining when a month is given only 29 days and when
>   it is given 30].
>
> The commentaries question why the Rambam (based on Nedarim 60b) speaks
>   of the month being lacking. Seemingly, it is quite obvious that if
>   there are only 29 days in a month, one would be permitted on Rosh
>   Chodesh in the next month. The new month has already begun. A point
>   that has to be made is that even if there are 30 days in a month, one
>   is permitted to partake of wine on the thirtieth day. Since it is Rosh
>   Chodesh of the coming month, the vow has concluded even though the
>   date is the thirtieth of the previous month.
>
> The Radbaz explains that this in fact is the Rambam's intent, even
>   though his wording is somewhat difficult to explain in that manner.
>   This interpretation is reflected in the wording of the Shulchan Aruch
>   (Yoreh De'ah 220:4). The Or Sameach offers a different interpretation,
>   stating that when a month has only 29 days, sometimes the conjunction
>   of the sun and the moon does not take place until the first day of the
>   new month. Even so, since it is already Rosh Chodesh, the vow is
>   concluded.

Comment: What if the wording of the neder was "I will not drink wine in the month of Shevat"? In this case are talking about the named month, not the idea that "whole month" is 30 days and "this month" is 29.

Comment: @Danno That is why the Rambam says "a month" meaning starting today a month, which goes for 30 days from the time the neder was made. A named month would be from Rosh Chodesh of that month until (and not including) the Rosh Chodesh of the next month. A named month is like saying "this month".

Comment: So naming Shevat in the neder would allow someone to drink when it is still Shevat? But saying "a whole month" (not naming) on the first of Shevat would stop someone from drinking until the 30th day is over?

Comment: Who says that any of this is even relevant to the question at hand? That is, who says that the idea of celebrating in Adar is subject to these technical discussions?

Comment: @mevaqesh, the asker does, in his last sentence. Personally, I don't think that sentence belongs there. But it's there.

Comment: @msh210 That may be the case, but at most this would be answering a side point in the question, and ignoring the main question; hardly a good answer.

Comment: @mevaqesh On the contrary, the last sentence is the critical one. Being marbim besimcha is part of this and follows the halachic rule. I added some clarification to the answer.

Comment: @Danno Rambam says that if someone says *for a month* in the middle of a month means 30 days from the day that the neder is given.

Comment: @sabbahillel yes, but saying "for a month" on the first of Shevat would include the 30th but saying "for Shevat" would not because the 30th is Rosh Chodesh so it "belongs" to Adar?

Comment: @Danno That is the way that I read it. In fact saying *for a month* of the first of a 29 day month would also include the 30th day, the first of the next month in all cases. That is one reason why one must be very careful on the language used in a neder and also why chaza"l prefer that one not make nedarim to begin with.

Comment: Can you bring a proof from Nedarim, which in general goes according to common nomenclature, to other areas of Halacha where that’s not necessarily the case?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this isn't an actual technical rule, and therefore does not have technical parameters. (perhaps this is part of the reason that Rambam, Tur, and the Shulhan Arukh don't mention this "rule").

Rather, the idea of increasing joy in Adar seems to be as the Meiri (Ta'anit 27b) writes, that:

> ובגמרא פירשו שכמו שמשנכנס אב ממעטים בשמחה כך משנכנס אדר מרבין בשמחה הכל הערה שראוי להתפלל ולהודות לאל בכל עת ובכל זמן כפי הנאות למה שאירע באותו זמן

That is, this statement is meant to inspire us to pray and praise God all the time, as is appropriate for what occurred then.

If, indeed, this isn't a technical halakhic rule, but rather an encouragement to not miss an opportunity to capitalise on a moment in time and channel it into service of God, then the question doesn't really start. If people are already excited, then that makes it an appropriate time to channel that into service of God. (See Kuzari II:50) for more on the idea of joy being a form of divine service when it is part of a deliberate experience, rather than mere unbound wildness).

Comment: `perhaps this is part of the reason that Rambam, Tur, and the Shulhan Arukh don't mention this "rule"` See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/93350/9643