# משנכנס אדר מרבין בשמחה - from first day of Rosh Chodesh?

Tags: adar

Does the increase of joy in Adar begin on the first day of Rosh Chodesh, since it is "Rosh Chodesh Adar" (even if it is not yet Adar)?

Comment: cf https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/80261/why-are-we-increasing-simcha-when-it-isnt-adar-yet

Comment: @magicker72 Dupe?